# Avoid shouldInterruptJavaScript in PySide QT4 - Python

Tags: javascript, python

I am using PySide '1.2.2' and trying to avoid the msgbox alerting a potential javascript error, since it is due to the site being sizeable.
I am using this code from this other answer:

[Override shouldInterruptJavaScript in QWebPage with PySide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868286/override-shouldinterruptjavascript-in-qwebpage-with-pyside)

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication
from PySide.QtWebKit import QWebPage

class QWebPageHeadless(QWebPage):
    # FIXME: This is not working, the slot is not overriden!
    @QtCore.Slot()
    def shouldInterruptJavaScript(self):
        print( 'not interrupting')
        return False
```

I have tried implementing the class above, and all sorts of derivatives of it, but with no success, it never gets to execute. Any thoughts on how to do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the "solution". Forget about PySide and PyQt, you will just end up with headaches, use Selenium. Very easy to implement and powerful for this purpose. Works great!